# CakePHP Observe field for validation check(already exists)

Tags: ajax, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

1. i have already user observe field in cakephp 1.3 Now i want to do the same thing in cakephp 2.0
   I have one form.there is a one field named email. When user insert email. onblur there is a popup one message that displays "email already exists" or "right"

for that i have write below code in my projects. the below code is my add file code

```
<?php $options = array('url' => array( 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'is_exist'), 'update' => 'email_exist');
        echo $this->ajax->observeField('UserEmailId',array('url' => array( 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'is_exist'), 'update' => 'email_exists'));  ?>
```

In my controller i have created one function like

```
 public function is_exist($id = null)
    {
    $result = "yes";
    $this->set('existdata',$result);
    }
```

i have also created is_exists.ctp fiel in view/uers.
 i dont know  why its not working.
i did the same thing in Cakephp 1.3 and its working file but not in cakephp 2.0
can anyone tell me how i implement this ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

because ajax helper is not supported in cakephp 2.
you need to learn how to implement it using the js helper
check this link : [js helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html)